# Why didn't Aragorn arrive earlier to save Boromir?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, character-motivation, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

In this scene, Aragorn was with Legolas and Gimli killing several Uruk-Hai. When Legolas hears the horn of Gondor, Aragorn hears it as well. Aragorn comes goes to aid him, but he was surrounded by many Uruk-Hai.

If we are going to look at Aragorn's situation, he has the upper hand. ***Why?*** He has Legolas and Gimli. If he has Legolas and Gimli to kill those Uruk-Hai, why does Aragorn arrive late? He has the advantage of arriving early to save Boromir because he is with Legolas and Gimli.

Comment: I assume, since you have a movie clip, you're strictly interested in a movie-based answer? The situation is different in the books.

Comment: I would be happy if you answer it separately. For example, In the book.... In the Movie...

Comment: Aragorn doesn't exactly *waste time* running towards the horn when he hears it.  The only orc he stops to fight (that we can see) is the one that *got right in front of him.*

Comment: He has LEgolas and Gimli and if that's the case, Aragorn should've arrived early

Comment: In the middle of a giant melee fight, you can't just ignore an enemy who's bearing down on you on the *assumption* that your friends will kill him before he kills you.  That's a great way to get stabbed in the back.  We can't see exactly what Legoalas or Gimli are doing when Aragon is blocked by that orc - they may have been fighting other orcs themselves.

Comment: They have the advantage

Comment: There is no 'arriving early', Aragorn cannot get there *before* Boromir calls for help. Having 'the advantage' doesn't give you the power to reverse time.

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 - "they have the advantage"... It's like 200 vs 4, dude.  The only reason they don't all die immediately is that the Uruk are spread through the woods.  WHAT advantage?

Comment: I'm talking about Aragon,Legolas and Gimli company. Legolas didn't even help aragorn in killing those uruks.So that Aragorn could have more time to save Boromir

Comment: Do you even take time to consider what you're asking? This is a ridiculous question. Why would Aragon save Boromir when in the source material Boromir dies? What would have to go through a directors mind to be like "oh wait lets save Boromir cuz yolo" no. No one would do that.

Comment: Edlothiad,What do you mean

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 as it has been said a few times, no matter how strong Aragorn and his friends are, he still needs to stop and fight the enemies that get in the way. Aragorn can still die with a single sword swing. He is fighting way towards Boromir, but he arrives too late. There was no way he could have arrived sooner since he can't ignore orcs that are trying to cut his head off.

Comment: But why did he arrived too late

Comment: Because to quote CyberClaw "there was no way he could have arrived sooner".

Comment: There's a way, Legolas and Gimli was with Aragorn right?My point is that Aragorn has the advantage because LEgolas and Gimli can help to kill the uruks.

Comment: What people have been trying to tell you is that Aragorn didn't NEED help in killing the orcs. There was only one orc who came between him and Boromir. The others were running the same way, but not slowing him down.

Comment: Why aragon didn't even ask Legolas help for it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## The Movie

Based on review of this clip, Aragorn hears the horn of Boromir and *immediately* begins running towards the sound (about 0:11 of the clip). One orc gets in his way, and he whacks it dead, an interaction that takes about 3 or 4 seconds.

Boromir takes at least a couple of minutes to die (he is still alive when Merry and Pippin are taken at 2:40); it doesn't appear that Aragorn's delay of a few seconds to kill the orc makes any difference to his time of arrival. Given that he started as soon as the horn blew, I conclude that **he came as soon as he was aware there was a problem, and this was not soon enough for him to prevent Boromir's death**.

## The Book

In the book, Aragorn runs up the hill to the Seat of Seeing at the summit. He is at this point unaware that there is an attack going on, though he has forecast that one is likely. He runs back down the hill towards the sound as quickly as he can:

> Even as he gazed his quick ears caught sounds in the woodlands below, on the west side of the River. He stiffened. There were cries, and among them, to his horror, he could distinguish the harsh voices of Orcs. Then suddenly with a deep-throated call a great horn blew, and the blasts of it smote the hills and echoed in the hollows, rising in a mighty shout above the roaring of the falls.
>
> 'The horn of Boromir!' he cried. 'He is in need!' He sprang down the steps and away, leaping down the path. 'Alas! An ill fate is on me this day, and all that I do goes amiss. Where is Sam?'
>
> As he ran the cries came louder, but fainter now and desperately the horn was blowing. Fierce and shrill rose the yells of the Orcs, and suddenly the horn-calls ceased. Aragorn raced down the last slope, but before he could reach the hill's foot, the sounds died away; and as he turned to the left and ran towards them they retreated, until at last he could hear them no more. Drawing his bright sword and crying *Elendil! Elendil!* he crashed through the trees.

In this narration Legolas and Gimli are not with Aragorn; he has gone off up the hill with only Sam, and Legolas and Gimli have been fighting the orcs on "the western slopes of the hill".

Again, then, we see Aragorn unaware that Boromir is in trouble until the horn blows, and running as fast as he can to assist as soon as he does hear the horn. And again, **he came as soon as he was aware there was a problem, and this was not soon enough for him to prevent Boromir's death**.

---

(all quotation from *The Lord of the Rings*, Book III, Chapter 1, "The Departure of Boromir")

Comment: I don't understand.Why legolas didn't help aragon to kill those Uruks

Comment: Which ones? There weren't any in the book, and there was only one in the movie clip you supply, and Aragorn didn't *need* any help to kill that one - as I say, it only took a few seconds to deal with him/her/it.

Comment: In the movies, the were uruks that are going to the horn of gondor as they heard it. But Legolas didn't even help aragorn with it

Comment: How would that have helped? It wouldn't have made Aragorn go any faster. He's already going as fast as he can.

Comment: Well legolas though is useful and helpful to aragorn's aid to save boromir

Comment: But he's NOT. To save Boromir, Aragorn would have had to arrive earlier at the scene. But if he's going as fast as he can, and he doesn't slow down for more than a couple of seconds, and he's *still* late (by more than a couple of seconds) - there's no way Legolas could have helped him get to the scene earlier.

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 Well, by the time anyone gets there, Boromir is already full of arrows.  Killing the one Uruk that was enjoying his death faster wouldn't have mattered to saving Boromir.  Stopping to engage more Uruk would have *slowed them down*.  This is why there's such confusion over your question.

Comment: What do you think Legolas and Gimli were doing? Kicking back with some draught and Lembas chatting about the weather? No they were killing orcs. They had no advantage. Aragon didn't need to save Boromir because that's the plot.

Comment: Edlothiad,So you're  saying that Aragorn doesn't need to save Boromir?  How traitor is he

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 You seem to be either very confused or deliberately trying to provoke an argument.

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 Are you asking why PJ didn't **change** the story from the book to have Aragorn save Boromir, even though there's no further role for him (because he's dead)?

Comment: Aragorn didn't even know that boromir was going to die. Why would he assume that in the first place?

Comment: Aragorn didn't arrive earlier **because Boromir didn't blow the horn earlier**

Comment: How brilliantly the books have been written! That quote of how Aragorn raced to Boromir, you can *feel* his need and desperation to reach Boromir in time :(

It makes the fact that he was late so much more sad